Multiple threading.Threads created using loop inside class can´t store right parameters
I wrote a Threader class using the threading module that creates multiple threads to perform a task (function) on a list of elements. I´m passing slices of said list into a threading.Thread object inside a loop, but when starting the multiple threads created, they all start using the same last slice.
import threading
from typing import Callable, TypeAlias, Union, Generator


SubjectType: TypeAlias = Union[str, int]

    
def list_chunks(lst: list, size: int)-> Generator:
    """
    Sublist generator. Splits a list into n sublist of specific size, yelding each sublist at a time.

    :param lst: List to be splitted
    :param size: size of each sublist
    yields each sublist 
    """
    for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
        yield lst[i:i + size]

class Threader():
    
    def __init__(self, function: Callable, n_threads: int = 5):
        """
        Instanciates a Threader object.

        :param function:
        :param name:
        :param n_threads:
        :param sleep:     
        """
        self.function = function        
        self.n_threads = n_threads
                        

    def create(self, targets: list, kwargs: dict = {}):
        """
        Creates multiple threadind.Thread objects

        :param targets: list of targets to be splitted between the threads.
        :param kwargs: kwargs to be passed to threading.Thread object
        """
        splits = int(len(targets)//self.n_threads) + 1
        targets_splitted: list[SubjectType] = []
        for sublist in list_chunks(targets, size=splits):
            targets_splitted.append(sublist)        

        self.threads: list[threading.Thread] = []
        for idx, sublist in enumerate(targets_splitted):            
            kwargs.update({'targets': sublist, 'thread_idx': idx})
            thread_ = threading.Thread(target=self.function, kwargs=kwargs)
            self.threads.append(thread_)
            print(f'Thread {idx} created. Kwargs: {kwargs}')
    

    def start_threads(self):
        """
        Calls start() and join() for each thread.
        """
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.start()
                    
        for thread in self.threads:
            thread.join()

Test code:
def simulate(targets: list, thread_idx: int) -> None:
for element in tqdm(targets, position=thread_idx, desc=f'Thread {thread_idx}'):
    if element % 3 == 0:
        time.sleep(1)
tests = [n+1 for n in range(25)]
sim_threads = Threader(function=simulate, n_threads=2)
sim_threads.create(targets=tests)
sim_threads.start_threads()

Ouput:

Expected two threads running on different slices of the test list, but can´t figure what´s wrong. Can anybody help me, please?

You have exactly one dictionary object called kwargs.  All the instances are sharing that same dictionary object.  If you need separate dictionaries for the threads, then you need to create a NEW dictionary each time.

Semi-related, it's somewhat dangerous to do kwargs: dict = {} as a default argument.  Every time that function is called, kwargs will start out with the SAME dictionary.  If you change the dictionary contents, the next call to create will default to that modified dictionary, which is no longer empty.

Thank you very much. Changed the kwargs.update to kwargs = {params} and it worked.  I´ll modify the default kwarg argument as well.

Why not **kwargs, which defaults to an empty dict automatically?

The problem is that your  kwargs dict is a mutable object, and it is not "frozen" just because you said it is the parameter for a thread - all of them receive the same dictionary object as parameter - and when they start, it is the last update they see.
So, to start, in Python, never do this:
def create(self, targets: list, kwargs: dict = {}):

Although this may not be what broke in te specifc case you hve, it will get you: the function declaration line is executed a single time during the program lifetime, so these default arguments for the function are the same mutable object - and whenever they change, they will retain the changes across function calls.
Do this instead:
def create(self, targets: list, kwargs: dict | None = None):
     if kwargs is None:
          kwargs = {}  # ensures the creation of a fresh dictionary each function call

Then, later, create each thread with a copy of the kwargs dictionary, instead of passing it directly:
        for idx, sublist in enumerate(targets_splitted):            
            kwargs.update({'targets': sublist, 'thread_idx': idx})
            thread_ = threading.Thread(target=self.function, kwargs=kwargs.copy())
            self.threads.append(thread_)
            ...

The .copy() call creates an instantaneous snapshot of your dict, and it is this object that is annotated in the Thread instance when it starts.
